# How can I make this code wait for the first function to finish before executing the second one or the function with less seconds?

Tags: javascript

```
  setTimeout(() => {console.log("this is the first message")}, 5000);
  setTimeout(() => {console.log("this is the second message")}, 3000);
  setTimeout(() => {console.log("this is the third message")}, 1000);
```

How can I make this code wait for the first function to finish before executing the second one or the function with less seconds?

Comment: By giving different wait times right. checkout how setTimeout works

Comment: I mean to execute 'This is the first message' first before the third one . if you notice the third one is only one second so it will be executed first but I want it to execute in order while waiting the required amount of seconds

Comment: The reason is because you are setting the timeouts immediately. And the time it is waiting for on the 3rd statement is only 1 second, where the first is 5 seconds. Setting the time out does not block the next action. `async await` can simulate blocking. Otherwise, you would want to set your timer inside the function passed to the first timeout

Answer (score 1):

```js
function delay(ms) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(resolve, ms);
  });
}

delay(1000)
  .then(() => alert("Hello!"))
```

Also you can make it to async/await

Comment: I mean to execute 'This is the first message' first before the third one . if you notice the third one is only one second so it will be executed first but I want it to execute in order while waiting the required amount of seconds –

Answer (score 0):

did someone say... `async await`?

```js
const wait = ms => new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, ms));

(async () => {
  console.log("this is the first message");
  await wait(5000);
  console.log("this is the second message");
  await wait(3000);
  console.log("this is the third message");
  await wait(1000);
})();
```